# Pyspark convert Year and week number to week_start Date & week_end Date

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to convert year & week number to the week start date and week end date using the Pyspark dataframe.

```
+---------+
|year_week|
+---------+
| 2019-W51|
| 2019-W52|
| 2020-W01|
| 2020-W02|
| 2020-W03|
| 2020-W04|
| 2020-W05|
| 2020-W06|
| 2020-W07|
+---------+
```

When I try to apply the following code, I am getting the error that column object is not iterable

```
df = df.withColumn('week_start_date', df.year_week.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(d + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")))
```

Error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

The expected result is :

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|year_week|week_start|  week_end|
+---------+----------+----------+
| 2019-W51|2019-12-16|2019-12-22|
| 2019-W52|2019-12-23|2019-12-29|
| 2020-W01|2019-12-30|2020-01-05|
| 2020-W02|2020-01-06|2020-01-12|
| 2020-W03|2020-01-13|2020-01-19|
| 2020-W04|2020-01-20|2020-01-26|
| 2020-W05|2020-01-27|2020-02-02|
| 2020-W06|2020-02-03|2020-02-09|
| 2020-W07|2020-02-10|2020-02-16|
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
 // week starting from monday, concat "-1", for tuesday "-2" etc.
    val p = df2.withColumn("week_start", to_date(concat($"year_week", lit("-1")), "YYYY-'W'ww-u"))
      .withColumn("week_end", next_day($"week_start", "SUN"))
    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------+----------+----------+
      * |year_week|week_start|week_end  |
      * +---------+----------+----------+
      * |2019-W51 |2019-12-16|2019-12-22|
      * |2019-W52 |2019-12-23|2019-12-29|
      * |2020-W01 |2019-12-30|2020-01-05|
      * |2020-W02 |2020-01-06|2020-01-12|
      * |2020-W03 |2020-01-13|2020-01-19|
      * |2020-W04 |2020-01-20|2020-01-26|
      * |2020-W05 |2020-01-27|2020-02-02|
      * |2020-W06 |2020-02-03|2020-02-09|
      * |2020-W07 |2020-02-10|2020-02-16|
      * +---------+----------+----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- year_week: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- week_start: date (nullable = true)
      * |-- week_end: date (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: This one is giving the previous week, anyway to show for the current week, for instance week 28 of 2021 should be from 12-jul-2021 to 18-jul-2021, but the data is generating for 05-jul to 11-jul

Comment: If using spark 3, use the configuration `config("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")`

Answer (score 2):

based on the response of Someshwar, only slight changes had to be made for python from scala.

```
df1 = df.withColumn("week_start", F.to_date(F.concat(F.col("year_week"), F.lit("-1")), "YYYY-'W'ww-u")).withColumn("week_end", F.next_day(F.col("week_start"), "SUN"))
```