# Pyspark - extract first monday of week

Tags: pyspark

Given Dataframe :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("James",202245),
    ("Michael",202133),
    ("Robert",202152),
    ("Maria",202252),
    ("Jen",202201)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Week", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

The week column denotes the week number and year ie; 202245 is the 45th week of 2022. I would like to extract the date on which Monday falls for the 45th week of 2022 which is 7th Nov 2022.

What I tried, :

Tried using datetime and udf:

```
def get_monday_from_week(x: int) -> datetime.date:
    """
    Converts fiscal week to datetime of first Monday from that week

    Args:
        x (int): fiscal week


    Returns:
        datetime.date: datetime of first Monday from that week
    """
    x = str(x)
    r = datetime.datetime.strptime(x + "-1", "%Y%W-%w")
    return r
```

How can I use spark functions to implement this, I am trying to avoid the use of udf here.

Comment: Does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030568/pyspark-convert-year-and-week-number-to-week-start-date-week-end-date

Comment: Thanks it worked, But I had to change the configuration `("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")` as I was using spark 3